# How get user location using iOS geolocation framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, geolocation, location, mapkit

I am looking to make an "If" statement, whereby I'm using the user's geolocation to create an outcome.  I do not know how to do this.

For example:

```
If (USERLOCATION = CANADA) {

//then do something here

}

Else {
//do something else
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the user location, you can use this code and match the country name with your. Although there might be a localization limitation.

```
- (void)reverseGeocode:(CLLocation *)location {
    CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
    [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:location completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {

        if (!error) {
            CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks lastObject];
            NSLog(@"Country: %@", placemark.country);

        } else
            NSLog(@"Error %@", error.description);
    }];
}
```

Then use `[placemark.country caseInsensitiveCompare:@"canada"] == NSOrderedSame` to match with the country you're looking for.

Comment: So if I use this how do I incorporate it in my If statement above?

Comment: Thanks. So if I have an enum statement, which defines the section number (i.e. enum
{
    sectionOne = 0,
    sectionTwo = 1,
    sectionThree = 2
}; ) how would I change the section numbers based on location? I was thinking an if statement, which contains your edited answer, however that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: What do you mean changing the section number? It looks like a different question from the one above.

Comment: I have a tableview, whereby I have different section, which I set out using an enum statement.  Originally I thought I could place an if statement in the enum statement, or vice versa, but it seems I cannot do this to test out whether your code would change the tableview section number (or order) depending on the user location.  For example, if you are in Canada, the sections will be sectionA, sectionB, and sectionC.  However, if you're in England it would be sectionC, sectionB, and sectionA.

Comment: Although the enum should work, don't forget to call `[self.tableView reloadData]` once you received the user data to reload the tableview. Some advice, I think that the best solution is to initialize your datasource with the right section order at the beginning instead of trying to figure it out in the tableview delegate methods. Since I've already answered the question above, can you accept my answer please? :)

Comment: Sure, I will. Thanks for taking the time to answer it.  Basically, I call the right section order in the beginning.  Do you know how I would go about changing the section numbers if the user is located in the UK?

Comment: You would wait to get the user location first. It means that you'd probably have a little latency (until the device finds the location). You could eventually display an `UIActivityIndicator` until you have that location. Then when you have it, you just have to build your datasource based on that.

Comment: Any idea how that would look?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to find a third-party API that can give an answer about whether a latitude/longitude is in Canada, or you will need to define a bounding box that means "Canada" and test whether your location is inside it.

Defining "Canada" by coordinates might be a little bit tricky because it isn't a square though there are significant parts that are nice straight lines. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9493049/189804) could help you define the box by supplying a list of bounding coordinates.